# Mojolicious Not Setting Cookie Domain

Tags: perl, cookies, mojolicious

I have been trying to set a cookie for my domain in this certain Mojolicious application and it will not do it. It keeps setting it to the local machine's domain.

```
 $c->cookie(
            goto => "DATA",
            { domain => ".mydomain.edu", path => '/' }
        );
```

I have been looking at this for hours and just can't seem to see where it is going wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem here was that I was running a base64 function to populate my value. This did not return a true string so I just had to set a new var to the return of the base64 function and then use that as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed:

```
$c->cookie(
                goto => encode_base64('data'),
                { domain => ".mydomain.edu", path => '/' }
            );
```

TO:

```
 $goto = encode_base64('data');
 $c->cookie(
                    goto => $goto,
                    { domain => ".mydomain.edu", path => '/' }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar`?

```
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $jar = Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar->new;
$jar->add(
    Mojo::Cookie::Response->new(
        name => "cookie",
        value => "1",
        domain => ".mydomain.edu",
        path => "/",
    )
);
$ua = $ua->cookie_jar($jar);
```